# Optimize a squashed migration in Django

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have created a squashed Django migration that looks similar to this:

```
add field "name"
run sql "CREATE FUNCTION x"
add field "age"
remove field "name"
run sql "DROP FUNCTION x"
```

Since Django cannot fully optimize the code between two `run sql` blocks, it is expected that `add field "name"` and `remove field "name"` are not optimized away. However, I know that the two SQL runs affects nothing relevant, so I can manually delete the `run sql` parts.

After having manually removed the `run sql` parts, is there any way to have Django run only the optimization step on the results?

Comment: What prevents you from manually editing the migration file before you apply it?

Comment: @dirkgroten: The real migration is a lot more complicated with many AddField, AlterField, RemoveField, etc. I can do it manually, but it's a tedious and meticulous process that I would trust Django to optimize better than I ever could. :)

Comment: There’s no other way. But the question is: does it matter? The only time you actually run this migration is in your tests, I assume (or if it’s a generic app that other people use once when they add your app). Will it make a significant time saving to generating the db tables to remove these superfluous commands?

Comment: I mean Django can’t know that the run sql command is not important and can be removed. Unless you remove it from the original migration file. Which you may do btw if it’s really irrelevant (and won’t affect any new db you setup, like the unit test dbs)

Comment: @dirkgroten: Yeah, maybe I explained it poorly in the question, sorry. I have made this squashed migration, then manually removed the RunSQL calls, now I'm looking for a way to optimize my (edited) squashed migration to see if it can optimize it for me after I've removed the RunSQL calls.

Comment: The docs say to not squash a squashed migration again until you’ve made it final (I.e. applied it everywhere and removed the `replaces` attribute). But after that, a new squash might actually work to further optimize. Haven’t tried it myself though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a command that uses Django's `MigrationOptimizer` to rewrite a single migration file, specifically for this scenario. I posted it as a gist here:

https://gist.github.com/jhillacre/7fa8c182dd821387d4cf1fdb9371dcd7

I've tested this in Django 1.11 using python 3.6. Not sure if there are changes required for Django 2+.

Gotchas include:

- the optimizer removing the initial flag from the migration.
- swappable dependencies being being distorted

I always diff the optimized migration and the original migration to make sure the changes regarding `initial` and `dependencies` are reverted.

Alternatively, you could remove these operation before squashing using the `RunPython` or `RunSql` `elidable` argument. From the docs:

> The optional elidable argument determines whether or not the operation will be removed (elided) when squashing migrations. [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/migration-operations/#runpython)

Comment: Not really sure what your question is. Are you looking for help making sure your code works with Django 2+? What goes wrong when you try to use it with that version?

Comment: @coralvanda: I don't think Joel is asking a question, rather answering mine :) The solution I chose was to remove the RunPython and RunSql calls from the existing migrations before squashing.